# Mistake in $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \rightarrow A \subseteq C \wedge B \subseteq D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

I am currently going through Velleman's *How to prove it* and I am trying to understand exercise 12 from chapter 4.1. The exercise asks to show whether the theorem in the title is correct. It is obviously incorrect as you can provide a counter example in the form of $A = \{ 1 \}$ and $B = C = D = \emptyset $, however I do not particularly understand the formal reason why the following proof might not work:

> Suppose $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$. Suppose $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, thus $(x,y) \in A \times B$. Therefore, since $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$, it follows that $(x,y) \in C \times D$, so $x \in C$ and $y \in D$. $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ arbitrary, so we conclude that $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$.

I understand, empirically why it does not hold for empty sets, but I cannot find the formal mistake in the logic, since we are only applying universal instantiation to $x$ and $y$, much like we would prove $(A \subseteq  B \wedge B \subseteq  C) \rightarrow A \subseteq  C$. There we would be supposing $x$ were an arbitrary element of $A$ regardless of whether $A$ is empty or not:

> Suppose $A \subseteq  B \wedge B \subseteq  C$ and suppose $x \in A$. etc. etc.

So my question is why does it work in the second example and not in the first one. Is there some formal definition of membership to a cartesian product which I am missing? Maybe something involving an existential quantifier? And if so, how is it different from the second proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to prove $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$ *simultaneously* when you write "Suppose $x\in A$ and $y\in B$".

However, this won't work, because there is nothing in the shape of your conclusion that allows you to assume that you can make *both* these suppositions at the same time.

If you're proving $A\subseteq C$ alone, you can start by saying "suppose $x\in A$" because if there *are* no such $x$ to choose, you're already done with proving everything you want about $A$'s elements.

But when you try to make both assumptions at once, then there might be an $x\in A$ that you need to handle, and then attempting to *also* choose a $y\in B$ (which is irrelevant for $A\subseteq C$) before you proceed will derail the proof if $B$ happens to be empty.

---

Written symbolically, you want to prove
$$ (\forall x. x\in A\to x\in C)\land(\forall y. y\in B\to y\in D)$$
You're allowed to pull the quantifiers out in front and instead prove
$$ \forall x.\forall y.((x\in A \to x\in C)\land(y\in B \to y\in D)) $$
but you *cannot*, as you do, go further and join the two assumptions $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ into an assumption for a single combined $\to$. This is a matter of propositional logic:
$$ (P\to Q)\land(R\to S) \quad\not\equiv\quad (P\land R)\to(Q\land S)$$

Comment: Bingo! my goal was actually in the form $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in C ) \wedge \forall x (x \in B \rightarrow x \in D)$ and I accidentally merged it into $\forall x ((x \in A \rightarrow x \in C) \wedge (x \in B \rightarrow x \in D))$ which is not true. Completely missed that, should have explicitly written the goal(and used a different variable for the second quantifier tbh). **Beat me to it**

Answer (score 2):

When you say that $y \in B,$ you're implicitly assuming that $B \neq \emptyset.$ There is no $y\in B,$ and so the proof has the hidden assumption that there is some $y \in B.$ In general, whenever you say "let $y \in B,$" you need to be careful that there actually is some $y \in B$ for you to pick!

Comment: It is also worth noting that this is a nice way to prove a set is empty; if you're trying to prove that $S$ is empty, say "suppose $s \in S$" and deduce a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We have only the assumption $$A \times B \subseteq C \times D\tag{1}$$

and we want to show $A \subseteq C$ (and also $B \subseteq D$). So pick $x \in A$, and we want to show $x \in C$ for the inclusion. To use $(1)$, we need a point of $A \times B$. We already have one in $A$, so pick $b \in B$ (here we use $B$ is non-empty!!), then $(x,b) \in A \times B$ by definition and by the inclusion $(1)$ we know $(x,b) \in C \times D$ and from that (!) we can trivially conclude that $x \in C$ and we're done. We need the point in $B$ to be able to use the inclusion $(1)$ and likewise to show $B \subseteq D$ we need some point $a \in A$ as well.

To prove the single inclusions we have only one coordinate in the product, and we need another one. The counterexample shows we cannot omit it.